# extract values from string with Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I have this java code

```
String msg = "*1*20*11*30*IGNORE*53*40##";
String regex = "\\*1\\*(.*?)\\*11\\*(.*?)\\*(.*?)\\*53\\*(.*?)##";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(msg);
if (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group((i+1)));
    }
}
```

the output is

```
20
30
IGNORE
40
```

How do I have to change the regex, that the String which is IGNORE is ignored?
I want to,that anything which is written there not to be found by the matcher.
the positions where 20,30,40 is are values for me which I need to extract, IGNORE in my case is any protocol specific counter which has no need for me

Comment: You mean this: [`\\*1\\*(.*?)\\*11\\*(.*?)\\*(?:(?!IGNORE).)*?\\*53\\*(.*?)##`](https://regex101.com/r/jA0fU1/1)?

Comment: or this `\\*1\\*(.*?)\\*11\\*(.*?)\\*.*?\\*53\\*(.*?)##` ?

Comment: Why do you place `()` around a part you don't need? Just remove those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always ignore the 3rd parameter:**

Simply don't create a capture (don't use parentheses).

```
\\*1\\*(.*?)\\*11\\*(.*?)\\*.*?\\*53\\*(.*?)##
```

---

**Ignore independently of position:**

You need to capture the `IGNORE` part just like you're doing, and check in your loop if it needs to be ignored:

```
String msg = "*1*20*11*30*IGNORE*53*40##";
String regex = "\\*1\\*(.*?)\\*11\\*(.*?)\\*(.*?)\\*53\\*(.*?)##";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(msg);
if (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        if (!matcher.group(i+1).equals("IGNORE")) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/SEPA39735)

Comment: Thank you! the regex in your comment below my question works fine as well!

Comment: That regex always ignores the 3rd parameter (by not creating a capture). It won't work if `IGNORE` is in another position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) to make sure you do not get a match when `IGNORE` is in-between the 2nd and 3rd capture groups:

```
\\*1\\*(.*?)\\*11\\*(.*?)\\*(?:(?!IGNORE).)*\\*53\\*(.*?)##
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA0fU1/1). In this case, the 3rd group cannot *contain* `IGNORE`.

The token is useful when you need to match the closest window between two subpatterns that does not contain some substring.

In case you just do not want the 3rd group to *be equal* to `IGNORE`, use a negative look-ahead:

```
\\*1\\*(.*?)\\*11\\*(.*?)\\*(?!IGNORE\\*)(.*?)\\*53\\*(.*?)##
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA0fU1/4)

Comment: your demo does not give me the right result. I don't want 'some' to be a match

Comment: And what is the result then? `Some` is not a match, it is placed into a group. You can remove the brackets and that's all.

Comment: Good, I tried to show how you can achieve what you need with just changing the regex. Surely you can also do that multiple ways in code.

Answer (score 0):

Split the input on `*` and treat IGNORE as an optional part of the delimiter, having first trimmed off the prefix and suffix:

```
String[] parts = msg.replaceAll("^\\*\\d\\*|##$","").split("(\\*IGNORE)?\\*\\d+\\*");
```

---

Some test code:

```
String msg = "*1*20*11*30*IGNORE*53*40##";
String[] parts = msg.replaceAll("^\\*\\d\\*|##$","").split("(\\*IGNORE)?\\*\\d+\\*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[20, 30, 40]
```